# Multi-input, multi-output autoencoder

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to create an embedding for two unique input sequences. So for each observation, take in a sequence of integer symbols and a time series vector, to create an embedding vector. It seems like a standard approach with one input is to create an autoencoder, have the data as both input and output, and extract a hidden layer's output as your embedding.

I'm using keras, and it seems like I'm almost there. Input 1 is of shape (1000000, 50) (a million lists of integers of length 50). Input 2 is of shape (1000000, 50, 1).

Below is my keras code.

```
##########################################

# Input 1: event type sequences
input_1a = Input(shape =(max_seq_length,), dtype = 'int32', name = 'first_input')

# Input 1: Embedding layer
input_1b = Embedding(output_dim = embedding_length, input_dim = num_unique_event_symbols, input_length = max_seq_length, mask_zero=True)(input_1a)

# Input 1: LSTM 
input_1c = LSTM(10, return_sequences = True)(input_1b)


##########################################

# Input 2: unix time (minutes) vectors
input_2a = Input(shape=(max_seq_length,1), dtype='float32', name='second_input')

# Input 2: Masking 
input_2b = Masking(mask_value = 99999999.0)(input_2a)

# Input 2: LSTM 
input_2c = LSTM(10, return_sequences = True)(input_2b)


##########################################

# Concatenation layer here
x = keras.layers.concatenate([input_1c, input_2c])
x2 = Dense(40, activation='relu')(x)
x3 = Dense(20, activation='relu', name = "journey_embeddings")(x2)

##########################################

# Re-create the inputs
xl = Lambda(lambda x: x, output_shape=lambda s:s)(x3)
xf = Flatten()(xl)
xf1 = Dense(20, activation='relu')(xf)
xf2 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(xf1)

xd = Dense(20, activation='relu')(x3)
xd2 = TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='linear'))(xd)


##########################################

## Compile and fit the model
model = Model(inputs=[input_1a, input_2a], outputs=[xf2,xd2])
model.compile(optimizer = rms_prop, loss = 'mse')
print(model.summary())
np.random.seed(21)
model.fit([X1,X2], [X1,X2], epochs=1, batch_size=200)
```

Once I run this, I extract the "journey_embeddings" hidden layer output like this:

```
layer_name = 'journey_embeddings'
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict([X1,X2])
```

However, the shape of intermediate_output is (1000000, 50, 20). Id like to get an embedding vector of length 20. How is it possible to get a shape of (1000000, 20)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @nuric, the following code works:

```
##########################################

# Input 1: event type sequences
input_1a = Input(shape =(max_seq_length,), dtype = 'int32', name = 'first_input')

# Input 1: Embedding layer
input_1b = Embedding(output_dim = embedding_length, input_dim = num_unique_event_symbols, input_length = max_seq_length, mask_zero=True)(input_1a)

# Input 1: LSTM 
input_1c = LSTM(10, return_sequences = False)(input_1b)


##########################################

# Input 2: unix time (minutes) vectors
input_2a = Input(shape=(max_seq_length,1), dtype='float32', name='second_input')

# Input 2: Masking 
input_2b = Masking(mask_value = 99999999.0)(input_2a)

# Input 2: LSTM 
input_2c = LSTM(10, return_sequences = False)(input_2b)


##########################################

# Concatenation layer here
x = keras.layers.concatenate([input_1c, input_2c])
x2 = Dense(40, activation='relu')(x)
x3 = Dense(20, activation='relu', name = "journey_embeddings")(x2)

##########################################

# An abitrary number of dense, hidden layers here
xf1 = Dense(20, activation='relu')(x3)
xf2 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(xf1)

xd = Dense(50, activation='relu')(x3)
xd2 = Reshape((50, 1))(xd)


##########################################

## Compile and fit the model
model = Model(inputs=[input_1a, input_2a], outputs=[xf2,xd2])
model.compile(optimizer = rms_prop, loss = 'mse')
print(model.summary())
np.random.seed(21)
model.fit([X1,X2], [X1,X2], epochs=1, batch_size=200)
```

Comment: I'm curious how this general approach wound up working for you? Was the middle layer of the model "informative" enough to cluster on?

Comment: Hi Dylan, if there is decent signal in the inputs it seemed to work reasonably well

Answer (score 2):

You use `return_sequences=True` in your LSTMs and return again a timeseries rather than encoding the sequence into a single vector of size 20. This returns shape (.., 50, 20) as it outputs hidden state of LSTM at every timestep. Presumably you want to encode all 50 timesteps into a single vector, then you shouldn't return sequences.

Comment: That makes sense. The problem is when I change return_sequences to False, and remove the flatten layer, I need X2, which is now 2d, to be shape (1000000, 50, 1). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can use a `Reshape` layer to add the extra dimension.